# Abrir uma url logo após abrir uma nova aba no browser (Selenium)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Estou fazendo um código para acessar uma página de gabaritos da minha instituição.

Objetivo: Na primeira guia, eu abro o livro digital; Na segunda guia, eu abro o gabarito.

Porém, eu tenho que fazer o gabarito de forma a entrar em dois links diferentes para finalmente poder entrar numa certa disciplina.

Minha tentativa foi fazer o seguinte: (Exemplo com o overflow)

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Firefox()

btlivro = driver.get("https://pt.stackoverflow.com") # Primeira guia
sleep(3)
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions')") # Segunda Guia
sleep(3)
btdisciplina1 = driver.get("https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask")
```

Mas o que realmente acontece é que a url dentro de `btdisciplina1` é acessada dentro da primeira guia, e não na segunda guia que acabo de abrir.

Resumindo: Como posso fazer para a url dentro de `btdisciplina1` ser acessada na segunda guia?

Comment: Pode controlar o acesso de abas assim como fosse pelo teclado, ctrl + t (nova aba) ctrl +1 acessar primeira aba ctrl + 2 acessar a segunda aba aberta. 

send_keys. Selenium dispõe desse controle usando a seguinte sintaxe Keys.CONTROL + 't' :nova aba... acessar a primeira aba Keys.CONTROL + '1) usando a sintaxe do import from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + '1'

Comment: Por algum motivo, isso não está funcionando no meu programa.

`body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")` pula linha

`body.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')`

Eu coloco isso, e ele simplesmente pula e ignora essas instruções 
(mesmo já tendo dado o import das keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de quase 3 dias, eu acabei conseguindo, através do método window_handles.

Essa foi a minha solução (comentada) usando os indices das guias , espero que ajude a todos que passarem pelo mesmo problema.

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Firefox()

buttomLivro = driver.get("https://pt.stackoverflow.com") # Abre primeira guia
sleep(1)
window_before = driver.window_handles[0] # Chama a primeira guia de "windows_before"

driver.execute_script("window.open('https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions')") # Abre segunda guia
sleep(1)
window_after = driver.window_handles[1] # Chama a segunda guia de "windows_after"

driver.switch_to.window(window_after) # Troca para a segunda guia
sleep(1)
buttomGabarito = driver.get("https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask") # Acessa o link na segunda guia
```